# Error Integrating sessions into my Flask app

Tags: python, session, flask

I am building a login system for a project that I am building. I current already have a registration system as well as a login system that will log a registered user. The next thing I am trying to do is get the users username that he logged in with and save it in the session so that they can access the website and its functionality.

What happens is once the user has logged in with the correct credentials, I want to save the users username in the session and rediect them to the main page of the web app.

Now I am getting the error as follows:

```
Session object does not support item assignment
```

and I can't find any working solution on how to fix this problem
Below is all the code that I have in my python file that is relevent to this error:

Before reading the code. I do have a secret key included but I am not going to post it on here.
The login does work properly without the session line towards the bottom of the route below.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask import escape, session
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = DBSession()

@app.route('/login', methods=['get', 'POST'])
def LogIn():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = session.query(Users).filter_by(Username = username).first()
        if user == None:
            flash('The Username does not match any records')
            return render_template('Login.html')
        elif password != user.Password:
            flash('The username/password does not match any record')
            return render_template('Login.html')
        else:
            flash('Successfully Loged In')
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('HomePage'))
```

Comment: On Which line of code is that error msg generated?

Comment: second from last line. without the line i am not getting error. Once i add that line i get the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing two completely different uses of the word "session".

The "db session" which you create from sessionmaker, and use in `session.query` is (more or less) the current connection to the database. It's what enables all the queries and updates that you make in Flask.

It has nothing to do with the "web session" that allows you to store user-specific data to a cookie or server-side store. That's what you import from flask in the second line of your code, but it's *overwritten* by the redefinition of `session` when you call sessionmaker.

You should call these different things. Ideally your call to sessionmaker should be assigned to something like `db_session`, which you then use in your query to User:

```
db_session = DBSession()
...
# use the db session here
user = db_session.query(Users).filter_by(Username = username).first()
... 
# use the user session here
session['username'] = request.form['username']
```

Comment: It worked. another small thing. Is there a way fro me to see the current session and what is stored in the session for development of my project

Comment: Since by default the data is stored in a signed cookie, you can examine the cookie using your browser's dev tools.